# How to loop the images in typedArray for my listview

Tags: android, listview, typed-arrays

I have 5 images in my typed array. I need to set this images to my list view. Now it will be set  for 5 rows in the list. After that which is blank. How to set the same images for remaining list in my list view?.

here is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="audioImage">
    <item>@drawable/audio1</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio2</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio3</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio4</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio5</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio6</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio7</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio8</item>
    <item>@drawable/audio9</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

To get typed array ,

```
 TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.audioImage);
```

and i have used arrayAdapter to get the view,following code is used to set the image from typed array in getView(...)

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
    iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));
```

Comment: post your adapter initialization code

Comment: @HRaval  setListAdapter(new ImageAndTextAdapter(mContext, R.layout.audio_list, audioArray, icons)); I am passing audioArray as arraylist and icon as typedArray .

Answer (score 0):

You can get lenght of your typedArray using `lenght` method [Typed array in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#length())
So this way, and loooping through as below,

```
for(int i=0;i<ary.length();i++){
.
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: @JIGARI know, But my question is, see if the length of typedArray is 5 it will assign the images to only 5 rows in my listview, after that i wont get image. I need to repeat the same 5 images after it reaches the end of typed array.